# How to monkeypatch locally imported module for Python testing with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, monkeypatching

I am working with a very large project and there are already a lot of test that use `pytest`'s `monkeypatch` fixture. I wish to patch a specific method from a class which belongs to an imported module for example:

```
from project.common import services
```

in the services package there is a class with a method I wish to patch for example:

```
services.utils.Calculations.get_area()
```

I try to `mock` and `monkeypatch` it:

```
mocked_get_area_method= Mock(return_value=500)
monkeypatch.setattr(
   'services.utils.Calculations.get_area',
    mocked_get_user_ip_method,
)
```

then I create an object in my test:

```
class TestCommon:
    def test_calculations(self,monkeypatch):
        mocked_get_area_method= Mock(return_value=500)
        monkeypatch.setattr(
           'services.utils.Calculations.get_area',
            mocked_get_user_ip_method,
        )
        calculations = services.utils.Calculations()
        calculations.get_area()
        mocked_get_user_ip_method.assert_called_once()
```

but I get an error saying: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'.`

I believe the error comes form the fact that maybe `monkeypatch` looks for objects starting from the high level main project folder. If i try to `monkeypath` with this path:

```
        monkeypatch.setattr(
           'project.common.services.utils.Calculations.get_area',
            mocked_get_user_ip_method,
        )
```

the monkeypatching works BUT then I dont get a `True` in my `assert` because I believe the monkeypatching has changed the object in the main projects but since I have already imported it and instantiate the `services.utils.Calculations()` from the locally imported module the patching does not work.

How can I make this work?

**Note:** The pytest is run from the main project directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the patch to the module that has the `from project.common import services` statement. So for example, assume I have a file `project/frontend.py` that looks like this:

```
from project.common import services


def a_method():
    calc = services.utils.Calculations()
    return calc.get_area()
```

I'd like to test that `a_method` correctly returns whatever value it receives from the `get_area()` call, so in `tests/test_frontend.py` I might write:

```
import project.frontend

from unittest import mock


def test_a_method(monkeypatch):
    fake_get_area = mock.Mock(return_value=2.0)

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        project.frontend.services.utils.Calculations, "get_area", fake_get_area
    )

    res = project.frontend.a_method()

    assert res == 2.0
```

Here, we're patching `project.frontend.services.utils.Calculations` because we've imported `project.frontend` and `frontend.py` imports the `project.common.services` as the name `services`.

Comment: I've placed a runnable demo [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-10253826/tree/main).

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply and the example. If I changed your test to look more like [this](https://gist.github.com/kziovas/b667cd8fa3307dee7e26166451c68ba6) it would be more similar with my case. Which seems to still work for your example but it doesn't work in my case. I am really baffled now.

Comment: If you can update your question to include an example that reproduces the problem you're asking about, it would be easier to directly address it.